# Left join bringing 2 different objects

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

**I could not make a better title, if anyone can do it please, help me out! Same for tags.**

I've made a JPQL to bring me one Object with a List of other Objects.

The thing that's happening is.

I've got 2 items in Novidade(DB).

I've got 2 items in ComentarioNovidade(DB).

1 of the items from Novidade, connects to all 2 items from ComentarioNovidade. The other has no ComentarioNovidade related.

JPQL returns a List of Novidade (it's supposed to be)

**I'm trying to make it return one Novidade with all ComentarioNovidade in it if it has any.**

It's returning 3 Objects containing Novidade and ComentarioNovidade separated.
[image: ComentarioNovidade]

My JPQL is like this:

```
from Novidade as n left outer join n.comentariosNovidade
```

The class Novidade:

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="CodNovidade")
    private Integer codNovidade;

    @Column(name="Mensagem")
    private String mensagem;

    @Column(name="CodigoCidade")
    private int codCidade;

    @Column(name="CodigoBairro")
    private int codBairro;

    @Column(name="MesmoBairro")
    private String mesmoBairro;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="CodNovidade")
    private List<ComentarioNovidade> comentariosNovidade;
```

The class ComentarioNovidade:

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="CodComentarioNovidade")
    private Integer codComentarioNovidade;

    @Column(name="Comentario")
    private String comentario;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CodNovidade")
    private Novidade novidade;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CodUsuario")
    private Usuario usuario;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend helped me out with that.

My JPQL ended up like this:

```
select distinct n from Novidade as n left outer join fetch n.comentariosNovidade
```